# django-cms / pillow deploy on heroku failing due to missing header filer

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I have an error pushing [this](https://github.com/sittizen/sc) project to heroku. (should be nothing exotic, just some hello world django-cms/blog I made in order to try the service)

Seems remote miss some required lib header:

```
[tons of verbosity]
remote:            building '_imagingft' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/app/.heroku/python/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o
remote:            _imagingft.c:60:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory
remote:            #include <freetype/fterrors.h>
remote:                                           ^
remote:            compilation terminated.
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

yet from my initial searches on google it seems pillow should compile correctly (tried both 2.* and forcing 1.*, they work locally through either manage runserver or heroku local ...)

Answer (score 0):

seems the problem lies in using Pillow<3 ( current django-cms dependecies install 2.0 ). forcing pillow to 3.0 in requirements fixed this